# Checked out a previous commit and began working on it however have lost the branch name

Tags: git, gitlab

I originally checked out and was working on a branch and after a few commits was getting a lot of errors lets say branch "featureFix123. I tried checking out a previous commit from this branch now and so I knew would be fine if i checked out a previous commit on this branch and started working on it.

Now however it shows as the commit name "332gdsh943" rather than the branch name "featureFix123" it is on. If I commit the changes made from this commit or push them to the remote will it still be done under the branch name I was previously doing or is there some commands I will need to execute in order to pull the branch head back to it?

Comment: What is the commands you used to "checkout to the commit"?

Comment: Just git checkout and the commit hash, so in the example git checkout 332gdsh943

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch is nothing more than a pointer to a commit hash. So when you checked-out explicitly to a commit hash, you have basically changed your `HEAD` to that commit hash without assigning any branch name.

You need to checkout again to your feature branch and somehow bring the changes onto it. `Cherry-picking` commits seems like an easy solution unless you've made a lot of commits in your branchless state.

```
git log
# Copy the commit id of the commit that you have done on "checked out branch"
git checkout featureFix123
git cherry-pick <copied_commit_id>
```

For future reference, `git checkout <commit_id>` is generally used to temporarily go back to that code state for evaluation purposes or to fork a new branch at that state. If you want to reset your current branch to the said state, then you should use `git reset --hard <commit_id>`.